# How can I convert text into a URL-friendly string?

Tags: templating, url, string, conversion

If I want to convert text into a URL friendly string for sharing text in a social media link, how would I go about that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was about to ask this question, but realized that it's closely related to **[this question](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/184/is-it-possible-to-convert-string-to-uppercase)**.

The answer, like in the above referenced question [lies with Twig filters](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/index.html).

Specifically, in this case, one needs to use the [`url_encode`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/url_encode.html) filter to convert the text needed.

**Example**

```
<a href="http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url={{ entry.url|url_encode }}&title={{ entry.title|url_encode }}&source=Xavier%20Creative%20House&summary={{ entry.question|url_encode|striptags }}" target="_blank">
```

In any case, I hope that helps others with this. I know how easy it is to forget that the answers sometimes like over in the Twig docs, and not Craft’s.

Answer (score 1):

It was clearly documented on [Twig Official Documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/url_encode.html) that we can use `url_encode` filter to convert it to url friendly string.

**Example**

```
{{ "path-seg*ment"|url_encode }}
{# outputs "path-seg%2Ament" #}

{{ "string with spaces"|url_encode }}
{# outputs "string%20with%20spaces" #}

{{ {'param': 'value', 'foo': 'bar'}|url_encode }}
{# outputs "param=value&foo=bar" #}
```